# textarea stays empty despite setting its .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 fields from which i select some values to be concatenated and posted in a div from which, on submit, i save into a database.
So i select values from 'tags1' and 'tags2' and after i push the button 'adauga' the concatendated values show in the textarea with id 'd11'. Up untill now everythign works fine, untill i press the button 'Clear' to clear the div from values. After that if i try to add values again it does not work, nothing is displayed in the 'd11' div.
Below is the html and the script:

```
<select name="tehnologie[]" id="tags2" size="13" multiple = "multiple">
    <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
    <option value="UMTS">UMTS</option>
    <option value="LTE">LTE</option>
    <option value="NR (5G)">NR (5G)</option>
    <option value="Radiodifuziune AM">Radiodifuziune AM</option>
    <option value="Radiodifuziune FM">Radiodifuziune FM</option>
    <option value="TV digital">TV digital</option>
    <option value="TV analogic">TV analogic</option>
    <option value="PMR/PAMR">PMR/PAMR</option>
    <option value="Satelit">Satelit</option>
    <option value="Aero">Aero</option>
    <option value="RAmator">RAmator</option>
    <option value="Alte aplicatii radio">Alte aplicatii radio</option>
</select>


<input name="banda_buffer" type="number" list="frecvente" id="tags1" >
<datalist id="frecvente">   
    <option value="800">800</option>
    <option value="900">900</option>
    <option value="1800">1800</option>
    <option value="2100">2100</option>
    <option value="2600">2600</option>
</datalist>

    
<input hidden type="text" id="tags3" >
<input type="button" id="adauga"  onClick="myFunction1();" name="adauga" value="+" />

<textarea id="d11" name="banda"  rows="5" cols="300" readonly class="form-control input-md"></textarea>  
<button type="button" onclick="ClearFields();">Clear</button>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onClick="alerta();" value="Salveaza" class="btn btn-primary">
```

And the js:

```
var cpvuri1=[];

var AreaToDisplay1=document.getElementById('d11');

function myFunction1(){
    var text1=document.getElementById('tags1').value;
    var text2=document.getElementById('tags2').value;
    var text3= text2 +' - '+ text1;
    cpvuri1.push(text3);
    AreaToDisplay1.innerHTML=cpvuri1;
                        
    
}
    
function ClearFields() {
     document.getElementById("d11").value = "";
     document.getElementById("tags1").value = "";
     document.getElementById("tags2").value = "";
     document.getElementById("tags3").value = "";
     cpvuri1=[];
}   
    
function alerta() {
   document.getElementById("tags3").value = cpvuri1;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're using both .innerHTML and .value to set / clear the textarea, respectively. Once you set value to an empty string, it overrides the .innerHTML and the textarea stays empty.

Comment: i changed this function ClearFields() {

          document.getElementById('d11').innerHTML = "";
              cpvuri1=[];
         }   and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use value rather than innerHTML

```
function myFunction1(){
    var text1=document.getElementById('tags1').value;
    var text2=document.getElementById('tags2').value;
    var text3= text2 +' - '+ text1;
    cpvuri1.push(text3);
    AreaToDisplay1.value=cpvuri1;
                        
    
}
```